# actionLayout not working on specific item

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer, menuitem

I am trying to recreate this Nav Drawer
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb5Of.png). However my app:actionLayout is not working on the item I want it to work on. It is working on one of the Subitems [My Nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfY1k.png) (I set it there as proof of concept). How do I get it to also work on the 
 item
        android:title="Labels"

Here is my drawer_view.xml

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
        android:id="@+id/menu_top">


        <item
            android:title="Labels"

            app:actionLayout="@layout/label_btn">

            <!--Button-->

            <menu>

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_labels"
                    android:title="Dynamic Labels" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_labels_new"
                    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
                    android:title="Create New Label"
                    app:actionLayout="@layout/label_btn" />


            </menu>

        </item>



    </group>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
        android:id="@+id/menu_bottom">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Settings"

            />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_feedback"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Feedback"
            />

    </group>
</menu>`
```

My activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.floridapoly.relaystopwatch.MainActivity"
    >
    <!-- Layout to contain contents of main body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/main_listview_timer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" >


    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and my label_btn.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```